# What is the name of this design pattern using Performer?

Tags: java, design-patterns

What is the name of the pattern that used Retrofit 2.0 and some other libraries?

**The old version**

some manager can load data sync and async by two different methods

```
SomeClass obj = someManager.getDataSync();
SomeClass2 obj = otherManager.getBigDataSync()
SomeClass3 obj = otherManager2.getMyDataSync()
```

or

```
someManager.loadData(callback)
otherManager.loadData(callback2)
otherManager2.loadData(callbak3)
```

Now istead uses a helper class

**New version**

```
Performer<T> performer = someManager.getSomeData(...);
```

then we can execute this action sync or asyc with listener

```
T data = performer.performSync();
```

or

```
performer.performAsync(callback);
```

Comment: What line you are asking about? `performer = ....` or `performer.performSync()`?

Comment: About all lines, check edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like Event-based Asynchronous pattern, as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw(v=vs.110).aspx

It is basically a concurrency pattern allowing easy use of both synchronous and asynchronous versions of methods.

Comment: Yes, it look like this.